# How to define gradient to circular progressBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-progressbar

I have added a progress bar like following in my layout, i also added a color to it, and it works fine.

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/color"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
 />
```

But i need to add a gradient color on it. I added a gradient in colors folder like following.

```
<gradient android:type="linear"
    android:angle="0"
    android:startColor="#dc0336"
    android:endColor="#ff7f00"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

and then i assigned this color to the `Progressbar`

```
 android:indeterminateTint="@color/gradientColor"
```

But this does not work, I need to know a way to add a gradient to the `progressBar`

Answer (score 5):

This is a late answer but I think this will help other people. Just Try Following the code.

**drawable/loading_progressbar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="1440">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="10"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <size
            android:width="60dp"
            android:height="60dp" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#b43787"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="#7036a3"
            android:startColor="#f0376f"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_progress"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading_progressbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You should use `android:progressDrawable` instead of `android:indeterminateTint`.

Your code should look like below:

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/gradientDrawable"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
 />
```

Use the following as your gradient Drawable. Name the file as gradientDrawable.xml and place it under your drawable directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3.5"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="2.5dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#ff7f00"
        android:startColor="#dc0336"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

I have tested your gradient and it looked like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried that code but its showing me horizontal progress bar

Comment: Weird as the same code works for me. @dev90 Have you tried to replace style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" with style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle" ?

Comment: It's not working for me. when I use the solution as is - I see the horizontal progress bar. when I change the style to the style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle" it's round but not with the gradient. when I remove android:indeterminate="true" and android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop", I see the correct drawable but nothing is animating.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can set gradient background to progress-bar as below:

<ProgressBar
   android:layout_width="75dp"
   android:layout_height="75dp"
   **android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"** />

**circular.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
  <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="10"
        android:useLevel="false">
      <solid android:color="#FA969C" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
      <shape
          android:shape="ring"
          android:thicknessRatio="10"
          android:useLevel="true">
        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#CC3037"
            android:endColor="#ED4A52"
            android:startColor="#A11210"
            android:type="sweep" />
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```